# Не пойму почему неправильный вывод (ответ задачи)

Tags: c++, c

Программа считает кол-во чисел 4 или 7, и, если их кол-во делится на число, состоящие из 7 и 4, вывод YES...

```
bool test(int z)
{
        while (z)
        {

            if (z % 10 != 4 || z % 10 != 7)
                return false;
        z /= 10;
        }
        return true;
    }
    int main()
    {
        long long x;
        cin >> x;
        int k = 0;
        while (x)
        {
            if (x % 10 == 4 || x % 10 == 7)
                ++k;
            x /= 10;
        }
        if (test(k) == true)
            cout << "YES";
        else
            cout << "NO";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Что-то странное условие... Итак, например, для ввода 1 2 3 4 44 77 - получаем сначала 1 (только одно число 4, чисел 7 нет). Затем проверяем - 1 не делится ни на 4, ни на 7, ни на 47, ни на 47747774 - значит, NO? У вас реально такая хитрая проверка - количество должно делиться на число, состоящее из цифр 4 и 7? Типа, ответ YES при вводе 94 чисел 7? (94 делится на 47)? Что-то у меня большие сомнения, что вы правильно написали условие задачи... Не поленитесь - перепишите условие полностью, как вам его задали...

Comment: "Счастливыми являются положительные целые числа, в десятичной записи которых содержатся только счастливые цифры 4 и 7. Например, числа 47, 744, 4 являются счастливыми, а 5, 17, 467 — не являются.

К сожалению, не все числа счастливые, поэтому мы назовем почти счастливым числами те, в которых количество счастливых цифр в нем — счастливое число. Является ли число n почти счастливым?"

Comment: Уже 2 дня бьюсь не могу понять в чем ошибка.

Comment: `if ((z%10 != 4) && (z%10 != 7)) return false;` ((НЕ 4) И (НЕ 7)). или НЕ((4) ИЛИ (7)), т.е. `if (!(z%10==4 || z%10 == 7))`

Comment: Harry, я попробовал твое условие при вводе 10000 1000000 100000000 и т.д. вывод YES хотя должно NO.

Comment: Я не знаю, как именно вы правили код, поэтому просто написал в ответе свой - см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот посмотрите этот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool isLucky(unsigned long long n)
{
    if (n == 0) return false;
    while(n)
    {
        if (n%10 != 4 && n%10 != 7) return false;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}

bool isAlmostLucky(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned int count47 = 0;
    while(n)
    {
        if (n%10 == 4 || n%10 == 7) ++count47;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return isLucky(count47);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(;;)
    {
        unsigned long long n;
        cin >> n;
        if (n == 0) break;

        cout << (isAlmostLucky(n) ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно пару вопросов: 1)В чем была моя ошибка? 2)Я еще не так разбираюсь в С++, поэтому мне еще сложно понять некоторые фрагменты твоего кода. Как сделать то чтоб он выходил из консоли?

Comment: 1. После исправлений (кстати, на будущее: **ни в коем случае не меняйте кардинально вопрос** после того, как задали! вы изменили код, и теперь наши ответы выглядят как ответы придурков - типа, сделай так, как у тебя и так сделано) - у вас не обрабатывается отдельно 0. Вводите 1000, получаете `k == 0`, но ваша логика считает его счастливым. 2. Ввести значение 0.

Comment: Спасибо больше, учту ваши советы.

Answer (score 3):

Сразу бросается в глаза

```
if (z % 10 != 4 || z % 10 != 7)
```

Это условие всегда заведомо истинно.